# Configure a VPC based on AWS example

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to configure a network based on [Practical VPC Design | AWS Startups Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/practical-vpc-design/).

```
10.0.0.0/18 — AZ A
10.0.0.0/19 — Private
10.0.32.0/19
10.0.32.0/20 — Public
10.0.48.0/20
10.0.48.0/21 — Protected
10.0.56.0/21 — Spare
```

I configured the subnet `10.0.0.0/18`, but then the `10.0.0.0/19` subnet is not allowed, since it's an overlapping definition.

What have I missed?

How can I configure the network as described above?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to know about CIDRs:

- `0.0.0.0/0` refers to the whole (IPv4) Internet
- `/32` refers to *ONE* IP address, eg `54.22.33.44/32`
- `/24` lets the last number change, eg `10.0.0.0/24` means `10.0.0.x`
- `/16` lets the last two numbers change, eg `10.0.0.0/16` means `10.0.x.x`
- Everything needs a [CIDR calculator](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) to stop your head from hurting

As to your design:

- `10.0.0.0/18` goes from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.0`
- `10.0.0.0/19` goes from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.31.255`
- `10.0.32.0/19` goes from `10.0.32.0` to `10.0.63.255`
- `10.0.32.0/20` goes from `10.0.32.0` to `10.0.47.255`
- etc

You probably don't need VPCs anywhere near this size. A `/18` network has over 16,000 IP addresses so you're probably wasting address space which will make it harder to peer them in future.

I would recommend using `/24` subnets unless you know that you will need more than 250 addresses in the subnet.

If you look at the subnet listing in [Practical VPC Design | AWS Startups Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/practical-vpc-design/), please pay attention to the indentation. For example:

```
10.0.0.0/16:   <-- VPC
    10.0.0.0/18 — AZ A   <-- Allocation Range, not a subnet
        10.0.0.0/19 — Private    <-- Subnet 
        10.0.32.0/19             <-- Allocation Range, not a subnet
               10.0.32.0/20 — Public   <-- Subnet
               10.0.48.0/20            <-- Allocation Range, not a subnet
                   10.0.48.0/21 — Protected   <-- Subnet
                   10.0.56.0/21 — Spare       <-- Subnet
```

Not every line is a subnet.

See also: [Classless Inter-Domain Routing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This minor, but meaningful, clarification about the IP addresses was essential. I needed it to settle the gap, since I understood the concept of CIDR notation and subnet masking and figured this IP addresses allocation is invalid.